# replace a string from a specified line number and column

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to replace from line number 4, the character "K" which is right after 19823 but not the "K" character which follows

```
19822SOL     OW60021   7.173   
19822SOL    HW160022   7.230   
19822SOL    HW260023   7.124   
19823K        K60024   8.427
```

so the new file should look like

```
19822SOL     OW60021   7.173   
19822SOL    HW160022   7.230   
19822SOL    HW260023   7.124   
19823exc      K60024   8.427
```

currently i do know how to use sed command to replace K from line 4 with exc such as

```
sed -i "4s/K/exc/g" <newfile>
```

but I do not know how to specify which column to select

Comment: I can use sed -i "4s/19823K  /19823exc/g" <newfile> but I want to avoid this ideally

Comment: OK, so you don't want to change a `K` that occurs after a `19823`; you want to change a `K` that occurs in the first column of line 4. Or do you want to change all the `K`s that occur in the first column of line 4? Or do you want to change a `K` that occurs in ***a specified** column* of line 4 (or some other specified line)? The simple solution of leaving off the ```g``` doesn't help if you want to manipulate a column other than the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just about that particular `K`, then getting rid of the `g` flag will do, as `sed` will only replace `K` once. Thus:

```
sed -i "4s/K/exc/" <newfile>
```

Namely, it replaces the first appearance of `K` with `exc` on line 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first `K`, just get rid of the `g` flag:

```
sed -i '4s/K/exc/' <newfile>
```

If you want to replace the 2nd, 3rd, etc. `K`, use `2`, `3`, `4` instead of `g`

```
sed -i '4s/K/exc/2' <newfile>
sed -i '4s/K/exc/3' <newfile>
```

If you want to replace all `K`s from the 3rd up to the end (only supported with GNU sed):

```
echo 'KKKKKK' | sed s/K/E/3g
KKEEEE
```

And btw, don't use double quotes (`"`) unless you really want to insert shell variables, command expansions, etc in the string passed to `sed`.

Comment: Note that using both a number and `g` as flags to the substitute command requires GNU `sed`.